# Manga about lost princess working as a maid

Tags: story-identification, manga

The rulers of the country that she is now working for are looking for her but don’t realize that she is the maid that’s currently working for them

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: Does this manga have any science fiction or fantasy elements? For example, does it have starships, magic spells, catgirls, or gnomes? If it does, please edit this information in to your question to prevent its closure as off-topic. As it is written, your story could be entirely historical fiction set in 18th-century Europe.

Comment: @Robert Columbia - If [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264933/122024) is correct, then the plot involves at least one fantasy element, in that the protagonist wished for a variety of skills she didn't possess at the time, and that wish was granted. The wish is made and granted in the first chapter, and the new skills start becoming apparent from chapter 2 onwards.

Comment: @LogicDictates but we *don't* know it is the correct answer unless the OP confirms.

Comment: @Robert Columbia - Yes, we don't know for sure that it's the correct answer, but it matches the description perfectly, and is the only manga/manhwa I could find that does. Therefore, I'd argue that we have sufficient reason to keep an open mind on this subject, rather than assuming that the story the OP is looking for is not on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

***[A Capable Maid](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/20vsej1/a-talented-maid)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> **As Maurina, she's on the run as the last of her kingdom’s royal line. Disguised as Marie, she is just a maid, serving the victorious empire.** She’s never been very good at anything, so when she's told to make a wish, she asks for the ability to help others and bring them happiness. Now as visions of brilliant and skilled people fill her dreams, she’s imbued with a bounty of abilities perfectly suited for any dilemma. **But will her secrets last as the crown prince seeks out both Maurina and Marie?**

When Morina's mother died, the emperor of the Clowan Kingdom found her and made her a princess, but ordered that she be kept in a remote part of the palace. She was kind-hearted, but lacking any real skills, she was viewed as being useless by those within the palace, and learned to avoid the gaze of others.

Then, three years ago, an illegitimate son of the emperor, Rael, slaughtered the royal family and took over the throne as the Crown Prince... or at least, that's how Morina remembers it. According to her, he wanted to kill her too, but she managed to hide from him by disguising herself as a maid. She now continues to work as a maid within the palace, using the name 'Marie.'

[image] [image]

Comment: As per the plot summary, there is a fantasy element to this manhwa.